# How can I enable editor layout in android studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio

I have just installed Android Studio and I can't see the layout editor. There is no Palette, component tree, design editor, and Attributes. What could be the problem as my computer has the minimum requirement for Android Studio?

Comment: "I can't see the layout editor" -- you might want to take a screenshot, upload it somewhere, and provide a link to it in your question. It will be difficult to help you otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio 3.6.1, and when you edit your layout you just see the XML, look for the toolstrip at the top of the editor:

[image: Android Studio 3.6.1 Layout Editor, XML Mode]

Click the little toolbar button with the "image" icon (mountains on a square, highlighted with the arrow in the above screenshot). That will switch you to the graphical layout editor:

[image: Android Studio 3.6.1 Layout Editor, Graphical Layout Mode]